# Rename SSRS Reports without changes the physical name

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to display a report name that is not the .RDL file name?

E.G: I have a report named "Rel_Errors.RDL" but I want to display this user friendly name as "Errors Reports".

But when I change the name in the Report Manager settings, and I deploy Visual Studio, it creates a new folder with the reports inside with the old name, instead of replacing the one I already renamed.

That is, I would not like to change the physical name of the file, just put a friendly name for the end user.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only option I see is to create a linked report with a more user friendly name that links to the original report. You can remove access to the real report for your users and grant them only access on the linked report.